# how to populate table view in react js using array elements?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am currently writing an iOS app using React js, how do I populate a list view using an array of titles?

This is what my code looks like right now for text in list view:

```js
View style={styles.rightContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.array }</Text>
</View>
// var array =   ["item1","item2","item3"];
```

And this is how I am fetching data:

```js
fetchData(){
    var  states_dictionary=['item1','item2','item3'];

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(states_dictionary),
      isLoading: false
    });
}
```

And this is what the list view looks like now:

[image]

How Do I make them appear properly?

Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define renderRow in Your ListView - similar to this:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => 
      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
         <Text style={styles.title}>{rowData}</Text>
      </View>
   }
/>
```

The renderRow closure is called with each element of the array as the only parameter, separately for each row.